# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EnumType'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I am using EntityFramework 6.2.0 in my project. I have a query like this:

```
result.Record = await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(x=> ((ServiceType)x.ServiceTypeId).HasFlag(serviceType)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It gives me this error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EnumType'.

Do I have to use like this?:

```
result.Record = await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(x=> (x.ServiceTypeId & (int)serviceType) > 0).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The first syntax is more clear for me. Is there any way to use HasFlag in the predicate?

Comment: Is your `ServiceType` enum decorated with `FlagsAttribute` ? What is the type of variable `serviceType` ?

Comment: Yes, ServiceType enum decorated with Flags. serviceType is a ServiceType enum variable.

Comment: i would do something like `await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(x=> x.ServiceTypeId == (int)serviceType).FirstOrDefaultAsync();` the reason it fails is serviceType can not be translated to Sql